# wordpress header image with logo and menu

Tags: wordpress, html, css, menu

I am creating a WordPress site with header top bar and header logo, I want the header of my site is looking like this header format

[image]

But I have to create the wordpress site, they create header and logo in the form of separate format. My created header is.

[image]

How to change header like on the first image format?

What is the problem in define header in wordpress?

Comment: create a demo with your code u can try.

Comment: What CSS have you tried? Do you have reduced test case on codepen or any code we can view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

- flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- or grid (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

for that.

Split the header into 2 columns. The left is the elephant image, in the right create 3 rows for stuff you need...